# "competition on this field" or "competition in this field"?

Tags: prepositions

Is it correct to say "A competition on this field" or "A competition in this field"? the latter sounds better to me but I'm not 100% sure.
To clarify: an example could be a competition among software developers to make the fastest application to solve a maths problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Would you kindly edit your question to explain what kind of competition and what kind of field you are thinking of? My answer covers most cases but, as I said, there are exceptions.

Comment: Hi. For example, a competition among software developers to make the fastest application to solve a maths problem.

Comment: Yes, that would be **in**. But please edit your question to add those details. That helps other users to easily understand your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about "field" as in "field of expertise", it would always be "in".

> He is the best **in** his field.
> I am an expert **in** the field of software development.

Answer (score 0):

Peter’s an expert in his field.--Longman
Are you still in the same field (= are you doing the same type of work)?--- Cambridge

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: it's almost always **in this field**. You can easily see this in this [NGram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20this%20field%2C%20on%20this%20field&year_start=1800&corpus=18&smoothing=3&year_end=2008&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20this%20field%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20this%20field%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cin%20this%20field%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20this%20field%3B%2Cc0). If you drill down and look at the exceptions, they can be summarised as:

- documents written by non-native english speakers
- where you are talking **about** the field: look for words like **data** and **book**
- when you are turning attention to the field
- when you are talking about the field as a whole, rather than some small part of it
- when you have some effect on the field look for words like **influence**, **impose**, **work**
- when you are talking about a battlefield
- in computer databases, you create an index **on** a field in a table.

Here are a few typical examples:

> It is finally argued that the progress of this work on autopoietic structures, more than on micelles, must be based on vesicles and liposomes, and preliminary work on this field is discussed.

> The vast majority of these deal with hi-fi preamplifiers and power amplifiers, and this book concentrates on this field.

> This is, first, because most of the previous books on this field are descriptive rather than explanatory in focus.